# Import TS file in JS file nodejs cannot find module

Tags: node.js, typescript, babeljs

I am migrating a NodeJS project to Typescript. I have already created the configurations and it runs with only JS.
I am using @babel/node to run it in a dev environment, but when I try to import a TS file into JS it doesn't work.

It throws the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './findById'
Require stack:
- src/CDBR/dynamicJob/infrastructure/repository/DynamicJobPGRepository.js
- src/CDBR/dynamicJob/infrastructure/DynamicJobModule.js
- src/Main.js
- src/index.js
```

This is the TS file where I declare my function:

```
const findById = async (dynamicId: string, database: Postgresql) => {
    ...
};

export default findById;
```

This is the JS file where I try to import it:

```
import findById from './findById';
```

> tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
  ]
}
```

> .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {"legacy": true}],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./src"],
      "extensions": [".js", ".ts"]
    }]
  ]
}
```

> package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "NODE_PATH=dist/ node dist/index.js",
    "lint": "eslint ./src",
    "start": "babel-node src/index.js"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/node": "^7.14.9",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.15.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.30.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "5.1.2",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "4.2.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2"
}
```

> `index.js` (root of the project)

```
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';

require('@babel/register')({
  extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
});

import Main from './Main';

const start = async () => {
  try {
    const app = new Main();

    await app.initConfig();
    app.initContainer();
    app.initServer();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

start();
```

Comment: Of course it doesn't, nodejs knows JavaScript, not typescript, also typescript before it runs it compiles the code to js

Comment: That's what babel-node is for

Comment: No, it is not. Did you already try with ts-node ?

Comment: `babel-node is a CLI that works exactly the same as the Node.js CLI, with the added benefit of compiling with Babel presets and plugins before running it.`

That's how I did it in other projects, but it doesn't work here for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I had to add "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime" to `.babelrc` plugins property and change the entry point to my app. This is how it looks like now:

```
require('core-js/stable');
require('regenerator-runtime/runtime');

require('@babel/register')({
  extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
});

const Main = require('./Main').default;

const start = async () => {
  try {
    const app = new Main();

    await app.initConfig();
    app.initContainer();
    app.initServer();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

start();
```